# APNs certificate missing private key when generating with custom keychain

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, keychain, private-key

I was trying to generate a new APNs certificate for my app on our **build server** but when I got to the *"Export 2 items"* step for the Certificate and Private Key, I found that I didn’t have two items.  My certificate didn’t have any private key with it.

I can see in my keychain that the certificate belongs to the **System keychain** whilst the public and private key are in my **CI-Jenkins keychain**.

I repeated the process on my development machine and it worked fine there.

The only difference being that the build server is currently set to use our custom **CI-Jenkins keychain** as opposed to the default **login keychain**.

Anybody knows what is happening there and if it makes sense? Do I need to swap keychain before generating the certificate and then swap back on my build server?

Comment: do you generate the CSR in same machine? I have similar problem previously and I re-create the cert step by step and then download the newly created cert to make it work.

Comment: yeah i created the CSR using Keychain on the same machine. I just tried again now and still same result. The certificate ends up in the System keychain and the key in my CI-Jenkins keychain

Comment: Hi, I am not quire sure how to fix it. Just a suggestion, you can try to remove the related items in your keychain and re-do the whole process again.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to just drag the certificate from the `System` keychain to the `login` keychain. Then it will automatically associate the correct private key with it.