# Private key missing when installing certificate on Keychain Access

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, p12

I need a private key p12 file in order to generate a PEM file for push notifications.

I found in many places the steps to create the file, but I always have the same problem on the final step:

1. Open Keychain Access on my Mac. Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority. This generates the CSR.
2. Login into my developer account. Create an unique Apple ID for my application, with push notifications selected (Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles > iOS Apps > Certificates > App IDs).
3. Open settings for the newly created appliction's id. Go to "Push notifications" and create an "Production SSL certificate". Upload the CSR when it ask for it.
4. When it finishes download the .cer file.
5. Double click on the certificate file to install it on the "Keychain Access" app.
6. Select the private key item under the installed certificate and right click to export it into a p12 file.

[Here it´s an screen shot of what i see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27ij8.png)

 But I can not find any private key item under the certificate item.

Please I really need someone to help me.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: try to search it under "Login" which is the first option on top

Comment: @NavneetGill Thanks. But I can not find it there either. There is only the certificate item.

Comment: The developer and/or distribution certificate you are using  has private key in login keychain ?

Answer (score 1):

I just got a similar problem looking for apns certificate so here is the solution if someone else need it : [APNs certificate missing private key when generating with custom keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945941/apns-certificate-missing-private-key-when-generating-with-custom-keychain)

Just drag and drop the certificate currently in the "System" keychain into the "login" keychain and you will get your certificate with its associated key in the "login" keychain.